# Alter primary key with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

First of all ASP.NET and MVC 4 are very new to me (+- one month) and sorry if its a bad question.

I've got two classes "Turma" and "Curso"

```
public class Turma
    {
        [Key]
        public int idCurso { get; set; }
        public string RefTurma { get; set; }
        public Curso Curso { get; set; }
        public string NomeCurso { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class Curso
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int idArtigoAT { get; set; }
        public string ConteudoPrograma { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Turma> Turmas { get; set; }
    }
```

After this I started a migration and updated the database. So far so good, but then problems.

Due to new information the primary key type should be varchar(18). I've tried to change but so far without success.

Any ideia or solution???

Comment: The primary key type should be varchar(18)? That is a sign of a bad design, it would be better to use a numeric value for the PK.... Can I ask why does it be a varchar?

Comment: I agreed with you but i need that "idArtigoAT" be the same type that a value that i receive from a query from another database (for example "10010000100010") and in my case the type is varchar(18).

Comment: What have you done to change it?  Did you change the property to a string instead of an int?  Did you use the column attribute to specify a varchar of a certain length or the fluent api? Are you making changes to your code-first entities and they are not getting reflected in the database?  Are you dropping the database before migration?

Comment: I change "public int idArtigoAT { get; set; }" to "public string idArtigoAT { get; set; }",  in my manager console type "Add-Migration xpto" and "update-database" and get this error:
"The index 'IX_Curso_idArtigoAT' is dependent on column 'Curso_idArtigoAT'.
The object 'FK_dbo.Turmas_dbo.Cursoes_Curso_idArtigoAT' is dependent on column 'Curso_idArtigoAT'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Curso_idArtigoAT failed because one or more objects access this column."
No changes ate made to the DB because of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you want is an 'Id' property and an 'MyCustomUniqueName' property. this custom property, should be and unique index in database. this is the best design for this situation IMHO.